# iOS: ObjectMapper mapping an array of objects without root field

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

Suppose that I have a `User` object:

```
class User: Mappable {
    var username: String?
    var age: Int?
    var weight: Double!
    var array: [Any]?
    var dictionary: [String : Any] = [:]
    var bestFriend: User?                       // Nested User object
    var friends: [User]?                        // Array of Users
    var birthday: Date?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        username    <- map["username"]
        age         <- map["age"]
        weight      <- map["weight"]
        array       <- map["arr"]
        dictionary  <- map["dict"]
        bestFriend  <- map["best_friend"]
        friends     <- map["friends"]
        birthday    <- (map["birthday"], DateTransform())
    }
}
```

And my `Json` contains an array of that object: `[User]` How can I map this array even if it has not a specific field name? This is what I did:

```
class Users: Mappable {

var users: [User]?

required init?(map: Map) {

        }

// Mappable
        func mapping(map: Map) {
          //What have I to put here??
        }
```

}

Comment: please before down voting explain why

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple you just have to use mapArray instead of map.

You just don't need to create new users class, only user class is enough to do this task

Use in this way

```
let arrUser = Mapper<User>().mapArray(JSONObject: JSONResponse.rawValue)
```

Comment: I got this error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'JSONResponse'` I'm using swift 4

Comment: this is the way i get my data.... you can use your data
. The array you are getting